# Python - Access protected network resource

Tags: python, windows, file, networking

I need to open a file on my local network from a Python script.

In the basic case is very simple:

```
fh = open('\\servername\path\resource.txt', 'r')
...
```

The problem is that the access to this network resource is protected. I tried something like:

```
fh = open('\\servername\path\resource.txt@username:pass', 'r')
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, backslashes in Python need to be escaped, so your path string is

```
'\\\\servername\\path\\resource.txt'
# or ..
r'\\servername\path\resource.txt'
```

Python's open function has no support for passwords. You'll need to use windows functions to specify passwords. [Here's an example program doing exactly that](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/).

Comment: And how to you access a "protected" network folder? It fails creating a folder, for example.